# How to detect when a job was canceled in Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, quartz.net, cancellation-token, quartz.net-3.0

I'm using `Quartz.net 3.x`, and following what little documentation I could find on the subject, I've implemented the ability for my job to be canceled, like this:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
  public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
  {
      //Do some stuff...
      context.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      //Do other stuff...
  }
}
```

This seems to work correctly, in fact when if cancel the job, by calling the following code

```
scheduler.Interrupt(myJobKey);
```

the job stops when it hits the next ThrowIfCancellationRequested() instruction.

However, the problem is that I have a `IJobListener` that, when a job finishes, needs to check if the job was cancelled or if it finished correctly. I've tried to implement it like this:

```
public Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
            {
    if(jobException != null && jobException.InnerException is OperationCanceledException){
        //doesn't work, when a OperationCanceledException was raised as a result of calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested() jobException is null 
    }

    if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested){
        //doesn't work either, IsCancellationRequested is always false
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I currently have a workaround where I set the job context's `Result` property to a custom value that tells me that the job was cancelled, but surely there's a "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to set a value in the JobDataMap? If cancelled, you set it to true and read it in the joblistener... https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/1.0/html/html/fb1bc96e-a6ac-6ca0-e3b3-b53b3bb28ecd.htm => _"Possibly useful for sharing data between listeners and jobs."_

Comment: @Fildor: yes, there are several ways to work around the problem, like using the datamap like you suggest or even just setting some data in the context's `Result` property, but I wanted to know if there was a more "proper" solution

Comment: You mean you expect there to be a more straight-forward solution like a `WasCanceled` property or maybe even a separate Listener-Method for Cancelled Jobs?

Comment: Did you try to alter the flag value? as mentioned herein 
Remarks: 
Note that if the flag for 'refire immediately' is set, the flags for unscheduling the Job are ignored.
https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/1.0/html/html/e155e960-3c46-0d5e-03fa-943f60544743.htm

Comment: @Fildor: well, since canceling means the Execute method throws an exception, I would have expected the `jobException` parameter in the listener to not be null, that's what is confusing me most.

Comment: @ParamjotSingh: I'm not using the "refire" flag at all.

Comment: You can use ISchedulerListener.JobInterrupted Method, to determine if there is an exception occurred while job executions. Check out this link :
https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/html/f086b570-943e-8b41-5a23-7e147b31245c.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem: apparently I should be the one to manually throw `JobExecutionException` inside the job's `Execute` method, Quartz doesn't automatically do it when the method throws any other exceptions. Or, at least, it doesn't ALWAYS automatically do it, because it was doing it when I re-threw other exception types... maybe it automatically handles only some types of exceptions?

I don't know, but this works:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
  public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
  {
      //Do some stuff...
      try{
        context.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      } 
      catch(OperationCanceledException ex){
        throw new JobExecutionException(ex);
      }
      //Do other stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine if you control all cancellation points yourself, but how to handle the case if you are passing the token to, say, an orm operation? Somehow the catch block is still not executed and quartz swallows the operation cancelled exception...